# jQuery MultiSelect Widget

Tags: jquery, widget, multi-select

Looking for a jQuery MultiSelect Widget that can handle thousands of items.

Really like this: http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/ but the performance on it after a few hundred items is terrible.

Suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest you design it differently; a 1000+ multi-select sounds awful to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a Javascript widget in existence that won't bring your browser to a grinding halt if you  try to select thousands of items.  First of all, who is going to want to scroll through a list of thousands of items?

If your potential list of items is really long, I'd recommend something like jQuery UI Autocomplete that can use AJAX to send a much smaller subset of items based on key strokes.  Here's an example that allows multiple selections:  http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

However, you're not going to want to use this to choose "thousands of items".  You may argue that you need a control that allows you to click on an item, scroll down a few hundred rows, then Ctrl-click to choose them all.  That's where a better design comes in.  How are those hundreds of rows related?  Can you create a hierarchy of groups to choose from?  As I said before, any control you attempt to do this sort of thing with is going to perform horribly.

Comment: Good response, I wish my boss agreed with your theory on performance ;)

Comment: @ResidualEnvy Well, your boss certainly doesn't have to agree with me if he/she enjoys unnecessary pain.  ;)  Unfortunately, I know first-hand how awful long multi-select lists can perform.  I used to maintain an application that used these on a search screen.  *cringe*

Answer (score 1):

This widget works surprising well with approx. 5000 items. I tested in FireFox...

https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect